# How to make a JOIN query MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, console

I have 2 mysql tables: `cs_lots` & `cs_lots_history`. Related: `id`=`id_lot`

[image: Таблица cs_lots_history]

[image: Таблица cs_lots]

I need to write a query that will display the ID of each lot of `cs_lots` in an array, as well as from the`cs_lots_history` user_personaname if ID = ID_LOT
Query, which i have:

```
SELECT cs_lots_history.*, cs_lots.id as csid, inv_id, inv_assets, inv_image, inv_color, inv_name, inv_rarity, inv_type, inv_price, price_ticket, places, now_places FROM cs_lots LEFT JOIN cs_lots_history ON cs_lots.id = cs_lots_history.id_lot WHERE active_lot='1' AND user_personaname='@Saundefined' GROUP BY cs_lots.id;
```

But the fact that it takes only 6 lots, as Table `cs_lots_history` Nick`@ Saundefined` only 6 purchases (unique id_lots). And if they do not, the result is not printed at all

If you do not specify the condition WHERE user_personaname - then get all 12 lots, but then there is no sense of the query, the array will not get this purchased item by user ..

I would like to do something like that displays all 12 items focusing on `cs_lots` while if the nickname is not found in`cs_lots_history` with `id` =`id_lot` then the conclusion is simple in a column to NULL.
Is it possible?

P.S. my php code if need.. -  :

```
$rows = array();
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT cs_lots_history.*, cs_lots.id as csid, inv_id, inv_assets, inv_image, inv_color, inv_name, inv_rarity, inv_type, inv_price, price_ticket, places, now_places FROM cs_lots LEFT JOIN cs_lots_history ON cs_lots.id = cs_lots_history.id_lot WHERE active_lot='1' AND user_steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."' GROUP BY cs_lots.id") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res2)) {
    $rows []= array(
        'id' => $row['csid'],
        'inv_id' => $row['inv_id'],
        'inv_assets' => $row['inv_assets'],
        'name' => $row['inv_name'],
        'inv_image' => $row['inv_image'],
        'inv_rarity' => $row['inv_rarity'],
        'inv_color' => $row['inv_color'],
        'inv_type' => $row['inv_type'],
        'inv_price' => $row['inv_price'],
        'price_ticket' => $row['price_ticket'],
        'maxUsers' => $row['places'],
        'nowUsers' => $row['now_places'],
        'my' => !empty($row['id_lot']) ? true : false   
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mite difficult to understand what you are after. I believe you want a query that returns all records from cs_lot table and to indicate if a customer purchased from that lot using the history table:

```
select cs_lots.id, count(h.id) from cs_lots left join cs_lots_history h
on cs_lots.id=h.id_lot and h.personaname='...'
where cs_lots.activelot=1 group by cs_slots.id
```

If a person did not buy a lot, then the count will be 0.

If you want the entire records from both tables, then you should not use group by:

```
select cs_lots.*, h.* from cs_lots left join cs_lots_history h on
cs_lots.id=h.id_lot and h.personaname='...' where cs_lots.activelot=1
```

This way the columns from the history table will be null if a person does not appear in the history table for a given lot id.

Comment: your query don't work http://i.shotnes.com/a/02/r1v1sjbc.nfk_560dd627410ff.png i need query result like this http://i.shotnes.com/a/02/itohwniv.g4n_560dd686e8c8f.png , but with WHERE personaname ... If i use + WHERE user_personaname - i have this result http://i.shotnes.com/a/02/dzfye03u.xxw_560dd6c574526.png it is very difficult to explain to you, but even if the user does not buy - the id want to display the lot ... and that the results were not 6... need 12 results, same count `id` of `cs_lost`, even if the user does not buy this, then just be a NULL column personaname

Comment: 1. You joined on the id field in the history table, not on the id_lot field

Comment: 2. I provided you with 2 examples, you tried the 1st one, although your expected results are more similar to the 2nd one.

Comment: 3. You should not add the personaname field just like that to the query, even if  mysql lets you with its default configuration.

Comment: big thanks u for notices, but i do not understand... I do not understand how do you mean that I made a query, Now I will try ...

Comment: `select cs_lots.*, h.* from cs_lots left join cs_lots_history=h on cs_lots.id=h.id_lot and h.user_personaname='@Saundefined' where cs_lots.active_lot=1 group by cs_lots.id;` i think this query work's , need check on site.

Comment: my fault. h.personaname = steamid :DDD all works nice. your 2 query is real. result : `$res2 = mysql_query("select cs_lots.*, cs_lots.id as csid, h.*, h.id_lot as chid_lot from cs_lots left join cs_lots_history=h on cs_lots.id=h.id_lot and h.user_steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."' where cs_lots.active_lot=1 group by cs_lots.id") or die(mysql_error());`
thanks you very much! you are the best. ;)